# ClassCastException error while calling method from CustomAdapter to MainActivity

Tags: android, casting

I have a `Fragment`, an `Activity`, and a `CustomAdapter`.

In my `Activity`, I have this method:

```
public void cart_items(Integer num) { /* ... */ }
```

In my `Fragment`, I used:

```
((MainActivity) getContext()).cart_items(qty);
```

THIS WORKED!

But in my `CustomAdapter`, which belongs to `Cart.class`, I used the same process:

```
((MainActivity)getContext()).cart_items(Integer.parseInt(data.getQty()));
```

This Line gave me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.claude.afinal.Cart cannot be cast to com.example.claude.afinal.MainActivity
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried creating a new method in my Cart.class

```
public void to_main(Integer x){
   //then calling the method from MainActivity
   //But ((MainActivity) getContext()).cart_items(x); Didn't work. getContext()cannot be resolved
}
```

What is wrong with the `CustomAdapter`?

Comment: Use Interfaces as a callback

Comment: `getContext()` apparently returned a `Cart` object. So why are you trying to cast to a MainActivity?

Comment: I have a TextView in my MainActivity. There is a "Delete" button in my CustomAdapter. Everytime the user clicks the "Delete" button, it will call the method `cart_items` so that when the user navigates to the MainActivity, the value of the textview has been updated.